# How make a per-pixel output on WPF/XNA?

Tags: wpf, xna

I want to draw like in the old qbasik, where you can into 5 lines and PSET (x, y) derive any graph, or Lissajous figures.

Question: what better way to go for WPF? and way for XNA?

Any samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF and Silverlight
WriteableBitmap

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

WriteableBitmapEx library. Tries to compensate that with extensions methods that are easy to use like built in methods and offer GDI+ like functionality:
http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

In XNA this isn't the most efficient thing in general, but I think your best bet is to probably create a texture and set each pixel using SetData, and render it to the screen with SpriteBatch.

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D t;
    Color[] blankScreen;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        //initialize texture
        t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);

        //clear screen initially
        blankScreen = new Color[GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height];
        for (int i = 0; i < blankScreen.Length; i++)
        {
            blankScreen[i] = Color.Black;
        }

        ClearScreen();
    }

    private void Set(int x, int y, Color c)
    {
        Color[] cArray = { c };

        //unset texture from device
        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
        t.SetData<Color>(0, new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1), cArray, 0, 1);

        //reset
        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = t;
    }

    private void ClearScreen()
    {
        //unset texture from device
        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
        t.SetData<Color>(blankScreen);

        //reset
        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = t;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(t, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

With this you can call either Set or ClearScreen at will in your Update or Draw. You may have to play with the texture index (I just used 0 for this example, might not be it for you), and also you only need to unset / reset one time per frame, so you can optimize that depending on how you use them.